# Continuous functions $f$ satisfying $f(x) = f(\sin(x))$

Tags: real-analysis

Find all continuous functions $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying $f(x) = f(\sin(x))$ for all $x$.

I don't have any idea of the solution.

Comment: Can you think of one? Can you think of another?

Comment: I edited your title to something more descriptive.  Please pay attention to this in the future.

Answer (score 7):

Hint: take any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and define a sequence $x_n$ recursively:
$$\begin{cases} x_0 = x \\ x_{n+1} = \sin x_n \end{cases}.$$

Then $f(x) = f(x_0) = f(x_1) = f(x_2) = \ldots$. Show that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = 0$ and use continuity.

Comment: Why $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=\infty$?

Comment: Did I write so somewhere?

Comment: Dang you, 7th upvoter. I had such an evil rep (666). :D